# Как считывать письма с почты?

Tags: php, email

Как считывать письма с яндекс почты?

Искал API у них - но у них API для почты домена только нашел..

Comment: imap используйте для доступа к почтовому ящику http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imap.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым делом нужно [разрешить получение и загрузку писем по IMAP](https://yandex.ru/support/mail-new/mail-clients.html#imap).

Пример загрузки сообщений из PHP по IMAP Яндекс.Почты:

```
$mailbox = '{imap.yandex.ru:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
if (!$inbox = imap_open($mailbox, 'you@yandex.ru', 'password')) {
    throw new Exception(imap_last_error());
}

foreach(imap_search($inbox,'ALL') as $msg_number) {
    // структура сообщения
    $struct = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $msg_number);
    var_dump($struct);

    // важные заголовки письма
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $msg_number, 0);
    var_dump($overview[0]);

    // тело сообщения
    $text = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $msg_number, 2);
    var_dump($text);
}

imap_close($inbox);
```

Разбор полученных сообщений заслуживает отдельного вопроса. [Пример разбора сообщений через API IMAP есть в документации.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002)